# Javascript window.open changes my URL

Tags: javascript, html, url-encoding

In my website view source I have this.

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?p[url]=http:\\www.abc.com','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');">
```

However when I clicked on it, the URL somehow changed to below and thus not working

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%5Cwww.abc.com
```

Seems like those symbol are automatically changes. Anybody has any idea how to get rid of this for a clean URL?

Thanks.

Comment: I know. How can I solve this so that I can a clean URL on the pop up windows and load properly?

Comment: You have a typo in your URL "http:\\www.abc.com". Use "/" instead of "\"

Comment: encodeURIComponent()

Comment: @zandroid sharp eye! what a silly mistake I have made.. Thanks for it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `unescape(decodeURIComponent(URL))` inside your `window.open()`.

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.open(unescape(decodeURIComponent('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?p[url]=http:\\www.abc.com')),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');">
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Incorrect. "http:\\" does not sound like a correct URL. And why decode URL via `unescape(decodeURIComponent(URL))`? You probably need to encode instead.